# How to copy IN, OUT, DURATION of each layer from Comp1 to each layer of Comp2

Tags: after-effects

I want to copy IN, OUT, DURATION of each layer from Comp1 to each layer of Comp2. Are there anyway to do that? or script?

[image: ]]

Comment: `var com1 = app.project.item(61); //1. Music
var com2 = app.project.item(62); //2. Track Name
for(var i = 1; i <= com1.layers.length; i++) {
    com2.layers[i].inPoint = com1.layers[i].inPoint;
    com2.layers[i].outPoint = com1.layers[i].outPoint;
}`

Comment: Good answer, but please put that as an answer rather than a comment. You might want to briefly explain how to run a script too.